# Struggling to PATCH a JSON response in Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to patch a JSON request using Google Apps Script. I'm trying to change the 'bidAmountMicros' object that looks like this from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/display-video/api/reference/rest/v1/advertisers.lineItems/patch)

```
    {
  "bidStrategy": {
    "fixedBid": {
      "bidAmountMicros": 0
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using Apps Script and I can't for the life of me work out where I'm going wrong. This is how I'm trying to do it-

```
    function updateBid(){
  var url = 'https://displayvideo.googleapis.com/v1/advertisers/' +
    advertiserID + '/lineItems/' + lineitemID + '?updateMask=bidStrategy';
    var body = {
      'bidStrategy': 'fixedBid',
      'bidAmountMicros': '4000000'      
    }   
    var result = JSON.parse(callApi_(url, 'PATCH', body, null));
  Logger.log(result);  
}
```

I'm think I'm going wrong in that the bidAmountMicros is within the 'bidStrategy' rather than a seperate object itself, but how would I call it from within that object? Sorry if this is a stupid question, pretty new to this.

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong? Any errors? Also your `callApi_` function is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the parts that were not defined in your code. This is how to create the JSON:

```
function updateBid(){
    var body = {
      'bidStrategy': {
        'fixedBid':{
          'bidAmountMicros': '4000000' 
        }  
      }   
    };
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(body));  
}
```